# ActionBarSherlock: How To Build ViewPagerTutorial? No build.xml

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager

I downloaded the ActionBarSherlock  ViewPagerTutorial from here:
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-actionbarsherlock-viewpager-tabs-tutorial/

But when I try to build the package it errors out saying:

```
$ ant debug
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

Where can I find the build.xml file for this package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where can I find the build.xml file for this package?

You create it, by [running the **`android update project`** command](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#UpdatingAProject).

Comment: And also needed:  **android update lib-project** in ABS/ .                Plus needed to edit both project.properties and set target=android-15